# What happens when you rescue an opposing civilization's settler from the barbarians?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

In Civ 5 G&K do settlers captured by barbarians stay as settlers when you take one from them if the settler is NOT from your civilization?

I remember capturing a settler that wasn't mine from a barbarian and it turned into a worker.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your own settlers get captured by barbarians, and you rescue them, they will remain a settler.

If any other civilization's settler gets captured by barbarians, rescuing them will turn them into a worker (if you claim it for yourself) or stay a settler (if you return it to them).